# How to change view automatically without any action in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I like to skip first page automatically in 2 seconds on my App .

Do I add code in js or html?

please, help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tabs (and states) are named 'tab1', 'tab2', ... and your app module is myApp, you can add in your controller this code:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $state, $timeout) {

    $timeout(function () {
        $state.go('tab2');
    }, 2000);

...

});
```

Comment: That's great !! It works very well. 
Thank you so much :)